# javascriptからのクリックを拒否する方法

Tags: javascript

こんにちは。
Youtubeのサイトを見ていた際に、全画面ボタンをjavascriptから押そうとすると

”Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.”

という警告がコンソール上に表示され、ボタンを押すことが出来ませんでした。
こういった挙動はどのように実現するのでしょうか？
ユーザのクリックと、javascriptからのクリックでなにか違いがあるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

フルスクリーンAPIはセキュリティ上の理由でclickイベントなどユーザー操作を起因して実行される関数内でしか実行できません。

そうしないと、timer(setInterval)でフルスクリーンを戻しても戻しても、解除させないなど作れてしまうため、そういう事が出来ないようになっています。

Comment: なるほど。素早い回答ありがとうございます！